# Python packages inside Mathematica's notebook: problem with sympy

Tags: python, external-calls

With Mathematica's notebook, sometimes I hit the `>` key at the beginning of a new line and start writing python code.

I can call and use the standard package numpy with `import numpy as np` without a problem. I have also installed other packages that work fine.

However, when I use `import sympy` it returns the following error message: "No module named sympy", as if sympy was not installed. But I can use sympy in the jupyter notebook. I have already updated it through anaconda, but without a difference. Is it possible to use sympy in Mathematica's notebook?

My mathematica version is 12.3.1.

The figure below has further details.

[image]

Comment: sympy is not part of core python installation. it needs to be installed separately after words.  Did you install it?

Comment: @Nasser, yes, I have sympy installed. It is working within Jupyter. My python installation comes from anaconda, which includes sympy.

Comment: Actually your comment was useful @Nasser. The problem was that I have different python versions installed, and Mathematica had not my anaconda version as the default one. In order to change the default one, I proceeded as explained in https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1948852 . After doing so, now sympy can be imported and used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow this Q&A, with Davi's comment-answer, seems useful:

> Actually your comment was useful @Nasser. The problem was that I have different python versions installed, and Mathematica had not my anaconda version as the default one. In order to change the default one, I proceeded as explained in https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1948852 . After doing so, now sympy can be imported and used. –
> Davi [14 hours ago](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257420/python-packages-inside-mathematicas-notebook-problem-with-sympy#comment641937_257420)

I thought I'd post it as an answer in case the Q is closed, but will delete if Davi wants to post.  If someone feels like copying the long answer from Community, this is a CW post, so go ahead.

Comment: From my side, it is great as it is @Michael E2. Good to know that you also find it helpful.